# pandas: select certain amount of rows based on column ranking using loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, rank

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
              'b':['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
              'c':[4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 10]})

   a  b   c
0  A  N   4
1  B  Y   5
2  C  Y   9
3  D  N   8
4  E  Y   1
5  F  N   3
6  G  Y   7
7  H  N   2
8  I  N   6
9  J  Y  10
```

Out of the 10 rows I want to select 5 rows based on the following criteria:

column 'c' is my rank column.

1. select the rows with lowest 2 ranks (rows 4 and 7 selected)
2. select all rows where column 'b' = 'Y' AND rank <=5 (row 1 selected)
3. in the event fewer than 5 rows are selected using the above criteria the remaining open positions should be filled by rank order (lowest) with rows where 'b' = 'Y' and which have rank <= 7 (row 6 selected)
4. in the event fewer than 5 rows pass the first 3 criteria fill remaining positions in rank order (lowest) where 'b' = 'N'

I have tried this (which covers rule 1 & 2) but struggling how to go on from there

```
df['selected'] = ''
df.loc[(df.c <= 2), 'selected'] = 'rule_1'
df.loc[((df.c <= 5) & (df.b == 'Y')), 'selected'] = 'rule_2'
```

my resulting dataframe should look like this

```
   a  b   c  selected
0  A  N   4     False
1  B  Y   5     rule_2
2  C  Y   9     False
3  D  N   8     rule_4
4  E  Y   1     rule_1
5  F  N   3     False
6  G  Y   7     rule_3
7  H  N   2     rule_1
8  I  N   6     False
9  J  Y  10     False
```

based on on of the solutions provided by Vinod Karantothu below I went for the following which seems to work:

```
def solution(df):

    def sol(df, b='Y'):
        result_df_rule1 = df.sort_values('c')[:2]
        result_df_rule1['action'] = 'rule_1'
        result_df_rule2 = df.sort_values('c')[2:].loc[df['b'] == b].loc[df['c'] <= 5]
        result_df_rule2['action'] = 'rule_2'
        result = pd.concat([result_df_rule1, result_df_rule2]).head(5)

        if len(result) < 5:
            remaining_rows = pd.concat([df, result, result]).drop_duplicates(subset='a', keep=False)
            result_df_rule3 = remaining_rows.loc[df['b'] == b].loc[df['c'] <= 7]
            result_df_rule3['action'] = 'rule_3'
            result = pd.concat([result, result_df_rule3]).head(5)
            return result, pd.concat([remaining_rows, result, result]).drop_duplicates(subset='a', keep=False)

    result, remaining_data = sol(df)

    if len(result) < 5:
        result1, remaining_data = sol(remaining_data, 'N')
        result1['action'] = 'rule_4'
        result = pd.concat([result, result1]).head(5).drop_duplicates(subset='a', keep=False).merge(df, how='outer', on='a')

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
                   'b': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
                   'c': [4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 10]})

    result = solution(df)
    print(result)
```

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work, can you show us what you tried and failed so we have some starting position please?

Comment: what should be the order of rows in the output if you have multiple matches for rule 1 or 2? By rank or by order in the original df?

Comment: each row or basically each letter in column 'a' can only be selected once. so if it is selected in rule 1 it is ignored for rule 2

Comment: Ok, what I meant was within a rule. Say you have 2 rows matching rule 2 and not rule 1. In which order should they be included? based on rank or first apprearace in the dataframe?

Comment: ah ok. based on rank (but shouldnt really matter as the df is constructed in a way that for rule 1 and 2 there should never be more then 5 selected in total). pls see my Edit to my original post. this should cover rule 1 and 2. i am struggling with rule 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def solution(df):

    def sol(df, b='Y'):
        result_df_rule1 = df.sort_values('c')[:2]
        result_df_rule2 = df.sort_values('c')[2:].loc[df['b'] == b].loc[df['c'] <= 5]
        result = pd.concat([result_df_rule1, result_df_rule2]).head(5)

        if len(result) < 5:
            remaining_rows = pd.concat([df, result, result]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
            result_df_rule3 = remaining_rows.loc[df['b'] == b].loc[df['c'] <= 7]
            result = pd.concat([result, result_df_rule3]).head(5)
            return result, pd.concat([remaining_rows, result, result]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    result, remaining_data = sol(df)

    if len(result) < 5:
        result1, remaining_data = sol(remaining_data, 'N')
        result = pd.concat([result, result1]).head(5)

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
              'b':['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
              'c':[4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 10]})
    
    result = solution(df)
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c
4  E  Y  1
7  H  N  2
1  B  Y  5
6  G  Y  7
5  F  N  3
```

Comment: thanks. i went with your answer and slightly modified it. still think though one can shorten the code a bit. but function definitely the way to go

Answer (score 1):

For your **4th RULE**, you have mentioned in your resulting dataframe, **ROW_INDEX 3** will come, but it has rank of **8** which is not lowest, **ROW_INDEX 5** should come according to the RULES you have given:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
          'b':['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
          'c':[4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 10]})

data1 = data.nsmallest(2, ['c'])
dataX = data.drop(data1.index)

data2 = dataX[((dataX.b == "Y") & (dataX.c<=5))] 
dataX = dataX.drop(data2.index) 

data3 = dataX[((dataX.b == "Y") & (dataX.c<=7))]  
dataX = dataX.drop(data3.index) 

data4 = dataX[((dataX.b == "N"))]
data4 = data4.nsmallest(1, ['c'])

resultframes = [data1, data2, data3, data4]
resultfinal = pd.concat(resultframes)
print(resultfinal)
```

*And here is the output:*

```
   a  b  c
4  E  Y  1
7  H  N  2
1  B  Y  5
6  G  Y  7
5  F  N  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create extra columns for the rules, then sort and take the head. IIUC from the comments then rule 3 already covers rule 2 so no need to calculate it separately.

```
df['r1'] = df.c < 3
df['r3'] = (df.c <= 7) & (df.b == 'Y')
print(df.sort_values(['r1', 'r3', 'c'], ascending=[False, False, True])[['a', 'b', 'c']].head(5))

   a  b  c
4  E  Y  1
7  H  N  2
1  B  Y  5
6  G  Y  7
5  F  N  3
```

Sorting on boolean column works because `True > False`.

Note: You might need to tweak the code to your expectations with different datasets. For example your last row `9  J  Y  10` is currently not covered by any of the rules. You can take this approach and extend it if needed.